# Have to display gif image keyboard in messanger android

Tags: android, keyboard, gif, ime

I am using the following code to display gif image, png image when clicking on buttons in the custom keyboard.when clicking on the button the images are sent in the hangouts but it is unable to send in messenger. The buttons are not in enable state.

what I have to do set buttons to enable state when this custom keyboard visible in messenger.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Here is the My code.

```
public class ImageKeyboard extends InputMethodService {

private static final String TAG = "ImageKeyboard";
private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.commitcontent.ime.inputcontent";
private static final String MIME_TYPE_GIF = "image/gif";
private static final String MIME_TYPE_PNG = "image/png";
private static final String MIME_TYPE_WEBP = "image/webp";

private File mPngFile;
private File mGifFile;
private File mWebpFile;
private Button mGifButton;
private Button mPngButton;
private Button mWebpButton;

private boolean isCommitContentSupported(
        @Nullable EditorInfo editorInfo, @NonNull String mimeType) {
    if (editorInfo == null) {
        return false;
    }

    final InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    if (ic == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!validatePackageName(editorInfo)) {
        return false;
    }

    final String[] supportedMimeTypes = EditorInfoCompat.getContentMimeTypes(editorInfo);
    for (String supportedMimeType : supportedMimeTypes) {
        if (ClipDescription.compareMimeTypes(mimeType, supportedMimeType)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void doCommitContent(@NonNull String description, @NonNull String mimeType,
        @NonNull File file) {
    final EditorInfo editorInfo = getCurrentInputEditorInfo();

    // Validate packageName again just in case.
    if (!validatePackageName(editorInfo)) {
        return;
    }

    final Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, file);

    // As you as an IME author are most likely to have to implement your own content provider
    // to support CommitContent API, it is important to have a clear spec about what
    // applications are going to be allowed to access the content that your are going to share.
    final int flag;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 25) {
        // On API 25 and later devices, as an analogy of Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION,
        // you can specify InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION to give
        // a temporary read access to the recipient application without exporting your content
        // provider.
        flag = InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION;
    } else {
        // On API 24 and prior devices, we cannot rely on
        // InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION. You as an IME author
        // need to decide what access control is needed (or not needed) for content URIs that
        // you are going to expose. This sample uses Context.grantUriPermission(), but you can
        // implement your own mechanism that satisfies your own requirements.
        flag = 0;
        try {
            // TODO: Use revokeUriPermission to revoke as needed.
            grantUriPermission(
                    editorInfo.packageName, contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "grantUriPermission failed packageName=" + editorInfo.packageName
                    + " contentUri=" + contentUri, e);
        }
    }

    final InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfoCompat = new InputContentInfoCompat(
            contentUri,
            new ClipDescription(description, new String[]{mimeType}),
            null /* linkUrl */);
    InputConnectionCompat.commitContent(
            getCurrentInputConnection(), getCurrentInputEditorInfo(), inputContentInfoCompat,
            flag, null);
}

private boolean validatePackageName(@Nullable EditorInfo editorInfo) {
    if (editorInfo == null) {
        return false;
    }
    final String packageName = editorInfo.packageName;
    if (packageName == null) {
        return false;
    }

    // In Android L MR-1 and prior devices, EditorInfo.packageName is not a reliable identifier
    // of the target application because:
    //   1. the system does not verify it [1]
    //   2. InputMethodManager.startInputInner() had filled EditorInfo.packageName with
    //      view.getContext().getPackageName() [2]
    // [1]: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a0f3ad1b5aabe04d9eb1df8bad34124b826ab641
    // [2]: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/02df328f0cd12f2af87ca96ecf5819c8a3470dc8
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }

    final InputBinding inputBinding = getCurrentInputBinding();
    if (inputBinding == null) {
        // Due to b.android.com/225029, it is possible that getCurrentInputBinding() returns
        // null even after onStartInputView() is called.
        // TODO: Come up with a way to work around this bug....
        Log.e(TAG, "inputBinding should not be null here. "
                + "You are likely to be hitting b.android.com/225029");
        return false;
    }
    final int packageUid = inputBinding.getUid();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        final AppOpsManager appOpsManager =
                (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        try {
            appOpsManager.checkPackage(packageUid, packageName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final String possiblePackageNames[] = packageManager.getPackagesForUid(packageUid);
    for (final String possiblePackageName : possiblePackageNames) {
        if (packageName.equals(possiblePackageName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // TODO: Avoid file I/O in the main thread.
    final File imagesDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "images");
    imagesDir.mkdirs();
    mGifFile = getFileForResource(this, R.raw.animated_gif, imagesDir, "image.gif");
    mPngFile = getFileForResource(this, R.raw.dessert_android, imagesDir, "image.png");
    mWebpFile = getFileForResource(this, R.raw.animated_webp, imagesDir, "image.webp");
}

@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    mGifButton = new Button(this);
    mGifButton.setText("Insert GIF");
    mGifButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ImageKeyboard.this.doCommitContent("A waving flag", MIME_TYPE_GIF, mGifFile);
        }
    });

    mPngButton = new Button(this);
    mPngButton.setText("Insert PNG");
    mPngButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ImageKeyboard.this.doCommitContent("A droid logo", MIME_TYPE_PNG, mPngFile);
        }
    });

    mWebpButton = new Button(this);
    mWebpButton.setText("Insert WebP");
    mWebpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ImageKeyboard.this.doCommitContent(
                    "Android N recovery animation", MIME_TYPE_WEBP, mWebpFile);
        }
    });

    final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.addView(mGifButton);
    layout.addView(mPngButton);
    layout.addView(mWebpButton);
    return layout;
}

@Override
public boolean onEvaluateFullscreenMode() {
    // In full-screen mode the inserted content is likely to be hidden by the IME. Hence in this
    // sample we simply disable full-screen mode.
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo info, boolean restarting) {
    mGifButton.setEnabled(mGifFile != null && isCommitContentSupported(info, MIME_TYPE_GIF));
    mPngButton.setEnabled(mPngFile != null && isCommitContentSupported(info, MIME_TYPE_PNG));
    mWebpButton.setEnabled(mWebpFile != null && isCommitContentSupported(info, MIME_TYPE_WEBP));
}

private static File getFileForResource(
        @NonNull Context context, @RawRes int res, @NonNull File outputDir,
        @NonNull String filename) {
    final File outputFile = new File(outputDir, filename);
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    InputStream resourceReader = null;
    try {
        try {
            resourceReader = context.getResources().openRawResource(res);
            OutputStream dataWriter = null;
            try {
                dataWriter = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                while (true) {
                    final int numRead = resourceReader.read(buffer);
                    if (numRead <= 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    dataWriter.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                }
                return outputFile;
            } finally {
                if (dataWriter != null) {
                    dataWriter.flush();
                    dataWriter.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (resourceReader != null) {
                resourceReader.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: As per android doc- To test your IME, make sure your device or emulator has an app that is able to receive rich content. You can either use the Google Messenger app in Android 7.1 or higher or install the CommitContent App sample. See -https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard.html